# Route 53 DNS not resolving when I run who is

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I recently purchased a domain on route 53.
Upon purchase I switched some ns records.
It's been 6 days since I did that and the ns records are not resolving.

When I do a WHOIS the NS AWS records are the old ones.
Now I switched to a lightsail server and those aren't showing.
When I go to Route 53 I see the ns records correctly set.

The domain in question is carestry.com
In aws route 53 the value for NS type is:

```
ns-1436.awsdns-51.org 
ns-1886.awsdns-43.co.uk 
ns-699.awsdns-23.net 
ns-304.awsdns-38.com
```

This is not what appears in the who is.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Whois does not use the DNS system for lookups, rather it looks to the registry for the domain. What's likely happened is the registry records have not been updated, so the records specified in the zone are not being found +as the registry records are used to populate the TLD (root) name servers with which DBS servers to look to.

Comment: How can I update the registry records on route 53?

Comment: Don't know.  Speak to the registrar for the domain.  If its Amazon, speak to them!  I do note most registrars allow you to set this information through a web interface related to domain registration.

Comment: According to AWS: Query your preferred Whois utility (domain registration lookup tool) for your website's domain name. so it suggest to use the who is for DNS look ups.  Unlike what you said.  Just FYI @davidgo

Comment: You can't use whois for DNS lookups. Whois tells you about the domain name registration  and the name servers for the domain. It does not contain any zone information. Whoid does tell you (nominally) the registrar for the domain name, but I would assume you know who you bought the domain name through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question after I found the solution.
It was confusing because on the home page of hosted zone files you get this page.  Where you can point to the name servers.

[image]

However this is NOT where you would set them.  There is another area under Domains -> Registered domains which also has name servers.  There you can add or edit the name servers.

[image]